# How to prevent loosing RDLC report body size?

Tags: pdf, report, rdlc

I have a RDLC report which should display information on one page in pdf.
I have a PageSize 21cm, 29.7 (standart A4).
I have a Page Header and Footer - each 2.5cm.
Body size 21cm, 23.7cm.
Margins for top and bottom - each 0.5cm.

So in theory it means that my page height is 23.7+0.5x2+2.5x2=29.7 - all seems to be fine.
In practice, for some reason, all elements placed after 23cm (body) are moved to the next page.

I cant get it, where is the problem and what is wrong if on RDLC all seems fine, but in pdf I am loosing 7mm of Body.

What it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Check your margin sizes in the report's property and eliminate any "white" space in the report - even horizontal. Even little bit of horizontal overflow would be "pushed" to second page.

Answer (score 0):

You set margin right and left to 0.5cm, then body width will be 20cm not 21cm.